# Is it possible to filter a taxonomy archive by other taxonomies that are on posts?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Alright. I've worked with Wordpress for more than 10 years. I've never had a need to do this before and I don't think it's actually possible without some pretty custom dev work. So let me set this up. An item can be added to a collection. This item also has other taxonomies - topic, artist, and type. On the collection archive, I have select-able lists on the page that list the other taxonomies that the items can have.

My question is, when I click on a topic to filter the collection, what is the taxonomy query I need to get **collections** that have **posts** that have a selected **topic**? To make it more difficult, I'm working inside of a theme with Elementor and Crocoblock's JetEngine/JetSmartFilter and I've been asked to use those plugins (or a shortcode) to make it easier for the team to copy it to future sites.

Happy to answer questions and thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on use case scenario you might need to write some custom code or a tiny plugin to achieve this. If you want to filter the posts in admin dashboard post list then you can use following code snipped to jump start

```
<?php
if (is_admin()){
   //this hook will create a new filter on the admin area for the specified post type
   add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', function(){
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

        $post_type = (isset($_GET['post_type'])) ? quote_smart($_GET['post_type'], true) : 'post';
 
        //only add filter to post type you want
        if ($post_type == 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_HERE'){
            $values = array();
            $query_years = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT year(post_date) as year from ".$table_prefix."posts
                    where post_type='".$post_type."'
                    group by year(post_date)
                    order by post_date");
            foreach ($query_years as &$data){
                $values[$data->year] = $data->year;
            }
            ?>
            <select name="admin_filter_year">
                <option value="">All years</option>
                <?php 
                $current_v = isset($_GET['admin_filter_year'])? $_GET['admin_filter_year'] : '';
                foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
                    printf(
                        '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                        $value,
                        $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
                        $label
                    );
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <?php
        }
    });

    //this hook will alter the main query according to the user's selection of the custom filter we created above:
    add_filter( 'parse_query', function($query){
        global $pagenow;
        $post_type = (isset($_GET['post_type'])) ? quote_smart($_GET['post_type'], true) : 'post';

        if ($post_type == 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_HERE' && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['admin_filter_year']) && !empty($_GET['admin_filter_year'])) {
            $query->query_vars['year'] = $_GET['admin_filter_year'];
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to do it in front end then my suggestion will be a `custom query` and `ajax`. For this scenario I'm for not be able to provide an example as it's a bit complex. As you have to use elementor in front end you can develop a widget for this too!

Comment: Thank you for your input - yes, I am trying to do it on the front-end. A widget or a shortcode will likely be the solution I end up with.